# Where to set timeout and file size values in PHP script

Tags: php, file-upload, installation

In order to upload large files in PHP I need to increase the file size / timeout values. I am not talking about changing the `php.ini`, but doing it at run time.

The corresponding values are

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

or `void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )`

But I wonder **where I need to set this**, or whether I can do it at all? Because when the upload data are sent, the script is only executed **after** the data are received. So the timeout kicks in, before I can increase it, or am I wrong?

So where would I need to apply the settings?

Comment: You answered your own question :-) It needs to be set in the php.ini.

Comment: Try to set all these before you send data to script, if possible. But the better way is to set it in php.ini

Comment: http://www.php.net/configuration.changes.modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all php.ini directives can be changed in the runtime. Even if they do, some directives don't make sense.

See the list of [php.ini directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php). 
Under **Changeable** column, any configuration that has `PHP_INI_ALL` can be changed in the run time (by your PHP script).

If you have access to the php.ini file, go ahead and edit it - don't bother with runtime changes. 
However, in certain situations, you will need to increase specific PHP configuration in the runtime.

`set_time_limit` resets the counter to 0, so your script can call this multiple times. This could be useful to set `max_execution_time` in `foreach` loops.

For an example, if you have to process a large file or something, you might want to increase the `max_execution_time` just for the instance.

From php manual for `ini_set`:

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration
>   option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and
>   will be restored at the script's ending.

Even though your PHP script cannot effectively change values, your .htaccess file can. 
(For `PHP_INI_PERDIR` directives).

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value  upload_max_filesize  2M
   php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
   php_flag register_globals                 off
</IfModule>
```

Again, give priority to the php.ini file if possible.